# How to calculate mean, median and std for for partial updated information?

Tags: pandas, numpy, mean, median

I have a `dataframe` (named: `basic_df`) with the following properties and characteristics:

1. The df has ~900K rows and 25 columns
2. Every few minuets (~9-10 minuets) the oldest rows (~5000 rows) are removed and new rows (~5000 rows) are inserted into this `dataframe` (`basic_df`)
3. From this `dataframe` (`basic_df`) I'm running a process which creates features.
   some of these features contains `mean/median/std` from the rows of `basic_df`

Is there an effective way to calculate the `mean/median/std` without going over all the rows. (i.e. taking into account the deleted and new rows and calculating effectively `mean/median/std`)

It seems to heavy to go over and over the ~900K rows while <1% data is new.